# Estimating the nested radical with $1,2,3,4,\dots$ under square root signs

Tags: inequality, radicals

I require some assistance in proving the following inequality:

$$\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}}} < \sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 + \cdots}}}} < \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{5}}}}$$

I'm not quite sure how to create a rigorous enough argument here, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, delete the question then.

Comment: Please delete your question, then.

Comment: Considering the upvotes (interest), should not the question be restored?

Comment: For posterity, the question was to prove the following inequality: $$\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}}} < \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 + \cdots}}}} < \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{5}}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

I was just curious if this was a way it could be resolved:

$0 < \sqrt{\frac{5}{2^4}+\sqrt{\frac{6}{2^8}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{2^{16}}+\cdots}}} <  \sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}}}$

This is true because each term in the middle radical is less than $1$.

$\implies 1 < \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\frac{5}{2^4}+\sqrt{\frac{6}{2^8}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{2^{16}}+\cdots}}}} <  \sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}}}$

$\implies 1 < \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\frac{5}{2^4}+\sqrt{\frac{6}{2^8}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{2^{16}}+\cdots}}}} < \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$

$\implies 2 < 2\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{\frac{5}{2^4}+\sqrt{\frac{6}{2^8}+\sqrt{\frac{7}{2^{16}}+\cdots}}}} < 1 + \sqrt{5}$

$\implies 2 < \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{5+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{7+\cdots}}}} < 1 + \sqrt{5}$

$\implies 5 < 3 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{5+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{7+\cdots}}}} < 4 + \sqrt{5}$

$\implies \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{5}}} < \sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 + \cdots}}}} < \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{5}}}}$

Comment: You have found a *consequence* of the statement. The question was to *prove the original statement*.

Comment: Edited for completeness.

Comment: If the last inequality is correct then you need to reverse the direction of all of you implications. You *started* with what you wanted to end up with.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar question about this when proving inequalities. If we go onto find a consequence of the original statement, can the original statement be validated if using an if and only if argument?